# Backup my custom iptables rules except fail2ban rules

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

### What I have

I have a few custom iptables rules blocking ports for everyone except my trusted IP addresses. Here's how I backed them up before:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
cat > /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables << EOF
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
EOF
chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables
```

Then I got fail2ban installed and configured. Everything works fine.

### What I want

Say I add a new trusted IP address rule. It appears in `iptables-save` output, but there are also fail2ban rules since it's been running for a while now.

I need to somehow separate and backup my custom rules, and leave the fail2ban rules/chains/etc. alone because those will get restored anyway.

### What I tried

First thing that comes to mind is passing `iptables-save` through grep and filtering out every line that contains `f2b-*`, but that doesn't seem clean or elegant and I'm not sure how reliable it is.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/870285/fail2ban-appends-to-chain-after-installing-iptables-persistent/930074#930074) suggests creating a new chain, but `iptables-save` [can't be restricted to specific chains, only tables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-save), and those [seem to be reserved](http://linux-training.be/networking/ch14.html#idp69741088).

[Cleaning up fail2ban rules](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2321) before making a backup doesn't seem like a good idea either.

I'm stuck, searched for a few hours to no result, to please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends (at least on the actions you use in fail2ban).
You can try something like this:

```
iptables-save | grep -vP '^(?:(-A f2b-|:f2b-)|-A INPUT\b.* -j f2b-)'
```

It should work in general case.
And this one to verify whether something with `f2b` prefix is there yet:

```
iptables-save | grep -vP '^(?:(-A f2b-|:f2b-)|-A INPUT\b.* -j f2b-)' | grep f2b
```